# Elements' order in a circuit

Tags: parallel, series, electricity, circuits

I was reading about source transformations and came across an example where there was a change in the order of two series elements, is this always possible? The same for in parallel elements but that makes sens since they have the same voltage.
[image]

Comment: As long as you don't care about a node voltage with respect to ground, which often does not matter, then yes you can swap series elements like this. What difference do you think it makes to \$v_m\$? Do you think it changes the voltage drop across the \$4\:\Omega\$ resistor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can always swap the order of two series elements and the circuit will still perform identically.